# Adjectives to describe a big human achievement vs. a quick achievement

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, adjectives, phrase-requests

**Premise:**

> It took 13 years and 3 billion dollars to sequence the first human
>   genome by *scientists*.

- What would be *an adjective* to describe this feat?

> However, now a new software can do the genome sequence in two hours, thanks to computers.

- What would be *an adjective* to describe this feat and it in contrast to the above?

**Basically, is there a word or phrase to demonstrate such a massive variance in effort and its corresponding achievement.**

Comment: (1) It is a monumental / prodigious feat. (2) An amazing  refinement of technique.

Comment: This appears to boil down to growth of computational power, which is allegedly _exponential_ (by Moore's law and other folklore).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for a phrase to display the comparison? if so you could use:

> What was once considered a **ground-breaking** feat is now deemed as
> **trivial**
>
> What was once an **extraordinary** accomplishment is now an **effortless** task

Comment: +1, for ground-breaking, however, isn't trivial evocative of sth that isn't deep or meaningful?

Comment: Yes, but trivial is also used to refer to sth that is not worth bothering about, or not worth mentioning. In software engineering, we sometimes use the term trivial to cite a processing component with relatively unimportant completion time (compared to other critical task which ultimately define the computational throughput)

Answer (score -1):

Humongous task can be used to describe the first task, number-crunching can be used for 'computer' or 'algorithm' based task.

Comment: I certainly wouldn't use *humongous* in any formal register.

Comment: I certainly wouldn't use *humongous* in any formal register. It has only been around since the 1970s, possibly coined, from the words *huge* and *monstrous*, with the stress pattern of *stupendous*. Seems typically something a drunk might have invented. *Gargantuan* means exactly the same, and has the advantage of 500 years of history behind it, being a voracious giant from Rabelais' book *Gargantua*.

Comment: Others are : Whopping, banging....just don't use it in a formal paper.